# Apply specific layout on Liferay portal page

Tags: layout, liferay, liferay-6.2

This is my first question, so sorry for the mistakes.

Actually, I want to apply my custom layout on liferay portal screen(s) like **new password screen** (physically that is not a layout and behaves like a pop_up over current page on first login, if password reset required is set to true).

This pop_up keeps on showing even if you manually change the URL in navigation bar, until you update new password.

And I am not able to find any way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Just go:

> Control Panel > Sites > {Your site name} > "Pages" category > "Sites pages" section >
>   Private/Public Pages

And select your Own Theme in "Available Themes" in order to save it.